Is it legal to have nested top-level microdata items?
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#encoding-microdata explains

Every HTML element may have an itemscope attribute specified. The itemscope attribute is a boolean attribute.
An element with the itemscope attribute specified creates a new item, a group of name-value pairs.
[..]
An item is a top-level microdata item if its element does not have an itemprop attribute.

However, it's unclear if nesting top-level microdata items in the markup is permitted. I.e. is this markup legal, defining two top-level (untyped) items, neither having any properties?
<div itemscope>
  <div itemscope>
  </div>
</div>


What did the W3C Validator tell you?

@Rob The validator accepts it -- but which part of the specification permits this?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemscope

@Rob If you post that (and maybe a link to validator.schema.org to support the case) as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

I'm not sure which part of the microdata docs I could quote that answers your question.
